# Magento: adding 2 or more static blocks to let category contents goes between

Tags: php, magento

I manage to add static blocks to my category pages, but what I am looking for now is to make **my category contents runs between these static blocks**, for example:

```
(static block contents)

(category contents)

(another static block contents)
```

so I can add simple contents in "**General Information**" "**Description**" area and the complicated slideshow and other common blocks runs in static blocks.

I hope I was clear in my question and thank you all in advance

Comment: please show the code (and layout.xml)

Comment: Hi hek2mgl, I don't have codes in this question, as I work thru admin area, I have added on static block to my category page in admin area and then I use these codes `{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/category/sacs-papier-luxe-pellicule.phtml"}}

{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/category/last-block.phtml"}}` in static block so it apears below each other, but if I want to add any contents in category it comes at first, what I want is to place it in between

Comment: you can call bottom static block manually in list page. Or create new module for adding this feature

Comment: Thank you DRAJI for editing my question, can you give me the details of creating new module, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way to achieve this is to add your static blocks in category_view page.

So these are the hints that you can refer with

1) Create two static blocks through admin (go to `CMS -> static blocks` and then add a new one). Let block identifiers be `top-category-static-block` and `bottom--category-static-block`. Make sure two blocks are enabled.

2) Go to

Location : `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`

add the following code  top of this file.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('top-category-static-block')->toHtml() ?>
```

add the following code bottom of this file

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('bottom-category-static-block')->toHtml() ?>
```

Remove the cache and then refresh the page. You can see the contents of your static blocks in  respective places.

**EDIT**

You can add any number of static blocks in anywhere any number of times. Use of the above snippet is endless and I think it has no  restrictions.

Answer for your doubts reside in this answer itself. I will explain it again for sake your best understanding

1)*Is it possible to add static block in different pages?*

Yes you can. For this you need to find the `phtml file` that render the content of desired page. Analyze the content in that page carefully and find the appropriate position and add the above code there. For example, above we added the code top and bottom of the category_view page. Similarly you need to find the appropriate position.

2)*Is it possible to add a static block middle of category page?*

Yes obviously. Why can't you make a try on the category _view file? Just try to add the above code snippet, somewhere middle of the page. It will do the magic

In magento, there may be lot of blocks that constitutes your particular page. For example, your category page constitutes by several number of blocks. Each part of the category page is rendering by different blocks. You can find every blocks that constitutes a category page in `catalog.xml` (Generally in layout file). So some time you may need to dig deeper to find the exact block in which you need to add the above the code in order to get the desired output. In initial stage, it may be a tough job. Later things will become more easy.

Don't give up. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you "programmer_rkt" very much for the solution it is working perfectly, but what if I need different blocks in different pages and what if I need to add some blocks in between the category contents, I know I am being difficult but I hope there is a way to do that

Comment: I have edited my answer.. Please check it. Approach me when you have any further doubts.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer, I think this goes closer to what I need, but my first question was not "same static block to different pages", I asked if I can add "**different** static blocks to different category pages, so page one has _static block 1_ and page 2 has _static block 2_ and these static blocks can come in the middle of category page contents, thank you again

Comment: Is it possible to add category description CMS programmatically based on layered navigation attribute selection, if color red chosen set CMS block id 10 to category description, if color blue set CMS block id 20 to category description.